# Flutter - background task

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I’m making flutter app and I need to implement notification even when app is closed. I found out two ways:

1. Use Background Task/Work Manager and read from API every 30 minutes and then display a notification.
2. Use Firebase to send push notification.

Which one is better? I like the first one because of simplicity but I am afraid of making the performance of the phone worse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great chance that you will have problems on ios with 1) Use Background Task/Work Manager

Comment: It will be app just for android.